# Math.Round(). My data is 10.17 , how can i round to 10.50

Tags: c#, vb.net, math, rounding

My data is 10.17 , i want get 10.50 after round . 
This code that i used `totQty = Math.Round(totQty, 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven)` but get 10.20.

Comment: By what logic does it round to `10.50` rather than to `10.0`, if you're rounding to `.50`s?

Comment: My first idea would be to round down then add `.50`

Comment: But i need to get 10.50. how can i round it ?

Comment: @TamásSzabó cant, if the value is zero then it will add 0.5.

Comment: So what you're looking for is *not* rounding but *ceiling*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever sory my mistake, i dont know what is it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this, you can multiply your number by 2, round up with 0 decimals, and then divide that by 2.

```
double rounded = Math.Ceiling(2 * value) / 2;
```

Comment: Thanks. Working .